How to compact an expression in subscript vertically?
I thought LaTeX would figure out by default that it should adjust some settings for the base of the logarithm in $\log_{2\sqrt[6]x}{1994}$ but it doesn't. The root symbol is too tall and extends too far down, I think; it should together with $2$ form a neat, streamlined base. Is there a recommended way to tell LaTeX to do a better job, preferably without coming up with some arbitrary number?

It would help if you provided a complete example, so that we're all working with the same output.  But to my eye, the subscript looks like a scaled down version of its normal self.  So is your question really about changing the $\sqrt$ symbol?  Regardless, "neat, streamlined base" is unclear (to me).  Could you explain what you want more objectively?

The root symbol is too tall and extends too far down, I think. (I previously used "high" instead of "tall", not being a native speaker of English. Edited.)

What are you wanting to have happen?  So far, you've said that it's too tall and extends too far down.  Are you wanting it shorter in both directions?  But having it shorter both below and above the x would not leave much room for the 6.

The $6$ could get smaller. What I imagine is something like that LaTeX knows to put limits of integration, summation or generalized product after the operator in subscript and superscript instead of below and above in inline math mode. And there are a few other differences. So maybe I should just surround my expression with \text{\( and \)}? I've tried it at https://latex2image.joeraut.com/, but the result is the same (also for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$).

Some suggestions, in no particular order:

When the amsmath package is loaded, the precise position of the 6 term can be adjusted via \uproot and \leftroot directives.

I'd also decrease the space between 2 and the square root term, as for me horizontal compactness may be more important than vertical compactness.

Finally, consider shifting down the entire 2 times sixth-root term.



Aside: I arrived at the suggested positioning adjustments while using the basic Computer Modern/Latin Modern math fonts. These suggestions may or may not "work" for other math fonts.
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for \uproot and \leftroot macros
\begin{document}

% no adjustments
$\log_{2\sqrt[6]x}{1994}$ 

% add \uproot and \leftroot adjustments, add '\!'
$\log_{2\!\sqrt[\uproot{-1}\leftroot{-1}6]x}{1994}$

% shift the whole subscript term *down*
$\log^{}_{2\!\sqrt[\uproot{-1}\leftroot{-1}6]x}{1994}$

\end{document}


I'm not sure why you're considering bad the output of that formula.
Anyway, you can shift down the radical symbol by pretending that the radicand is deeper than it actually is.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

No adjustment:
\[
\log_{2\sqrt[6]{x}}{1994}
\]

Shift down:
\[
\log_{2\sqrt[6]{x\vphantom{y}}}{1994}
\]

\end{document}


I'd definitely prefer the top one, with no adjustment (assuming that I'd write such a formula to begin with, which I'm not).

The root symbol is too tall and extends too far down, I think. (I previously used "high" instead of "tall", not being a native speaker of English. Edited.)

@ByteEater -- The only way I see to force the root symbol to be smaller is to force a smaller 6.  I'm not sure how that might be done, and am not able to experiment just now.
